# Does dark energy violate causality?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, causality, dark-energy

Assume a perfect fluid with $p = w \rho$, approximately flat space-time and the existence of a hidrostatic equilibrium solution $\rho_0$ for $\rho$. With the definition of the speed of sound $c_s^2 = \partial p /\partial \rho$ for adiabatic perturbations, the linearization of the Euler's equations yield: $\nabla^2 \rho_1 - \frac{1}{c_s^2}\partial_t^2 \rho_1 = 0$, where $\rho_1 = \rho - \rho_0$ (*Problem book in General Relativity and Gravitation*, A.P. Lightman, Princeton, p.221).
Now suppose that $w = -1$ as for dark energy. We get Laplace's equation in 4 dimensions. Hence an initial perturbation will propagate with superlumminal velocity because the Green's function for the Laplacian is always non-zero even outside the light-cone (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207675/greens-function-solution-to-4d-laplace-equation). This seems to contradict causality.
This reasoning has to be flawed because $w = -1$ dark energy is considered everywhere in cosmological models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model). In fact perturbations of this kind of fluid in the early Universe are very important in determining the large scale structure of matter nowadays. Arguments from authority aside, one can check that this fluid satisfies the dominant energy condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition), so one could say that energy does not propagate superluminally. What is the resolution to this?
I suspect that my assumptions are too naive. For instance, the supposed equilibrium solution will have to modify the metric, so that causality is restored in some way. I have tried to read some references, but I have not been able to get a "short" answer by myself.